# ghci : module import without errors, but then not found

Tags: haskell, ghci

I did in ghci several imports, among them

```
import Data.Map
```

There was no error message, and the ghci prompt indeed shows

> Prelude System.Random Data.List Data.Map Data.Set>

I wanted now to check the [maximum size of a map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map.html) and entered

```
Data.Map.maxBound
```

which gave the error message:

*:5:1: error:*

*Not in scope: ‘Data.Map.maxBound’ No module named ‘Data.Map’ is imported.*

Why does ghci now suddenly say that I don't have such a module?

**UPDATE**: The error seems to occur only when trying to access `maxBound`. For instance, when using `Data.Map.fold`, I get the expected *Data.Map.fold is gone. Use foldr.*, so Data.Map kind of seems to be loaded, but still with maxBound, it claims that there is no Data.Map module....

From the docs about `maxBound`:

> The size of the map must not exceed maxBound::Int. Violation of this condition is not detected and if the size limit is exceeded, its behaviour is undefined.

Comment: That error message does seem rather unhelpful (because it's totally inaccurate), but `Data.Map.maxBound` doesn't exist - `maxBound` isn't defined in `Data.Map`. It exists for any type which is an instance of `Bounded`. `Int` is such a type, so `maxBound::Int` exists (its precise value will depend on your machine), but you don't need `Data.Map` to access this. The warning in the `Data.Map` docs is just telling you that if you have an enormous map with more than that many elements, things won't work as expected.

Comment: I see. How would I access for instance the `maxBound` value for `Int`? Typing `maxBound::Int` says _Variable not in scope_. Typing just `maxBound` works, but yields the empty list.

Comment: `maxBound::Int` works fine for me in GHCi, with no additional setup and no modules loaded other than the Prelude. I'm afraid I've no idea why it might not be working for you (especially since simply `maxBound` works - and the result isn't an empty list btw, it's `()`, the so-called "unit" value, which is essentially an empty *tuple*.)

Comment: Strange. I have ghci 8.6.5. But I found that I get the error only when loading ghci via the stack environment (`stack exec -- ghci`). If I load a plain `ghci`, it works and delivers the value 9223372036854775807.

Comment: Ah, yes I tried it just running normal ghci. Not sure why running it via stack would cause this problem - perhaps it's something to do with the dependencies of the particular project you're running it under? (Still seems weird though.)

Comment: I don't have any project defined with Stack, just using it for ghci. I enter ghci, then do a `:l` of my Haskell file and see how it works. Actually, the only reason I use Stack is to have a random number generator available.